# How do I disable Data conection warning from other workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a issue trying to disable the data connection warning. This always happen when the code open two workbooks which has some data connection. Is there a way that i could disable these warnings?
Notice that these warning's appears in the follow lines:
Set wbsource2 = Workbooks.Open(filepath2)
Set wbsource3 = Workbooks.Open(filepath3)

Here's my code:

```
Sub Check_SS()
Dim filepath1 As String
Dim filepath2 As String
Dim filepath3 As String
Dim wbsource As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


KKS = Application.InputBox("Digite um KKS")
If KKS = False Then
    GoTo Fim
End If


User = (Environ$("Username"))
filepath1 = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Box\UTE\O&M.xlsx"
filepath2 = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Box\UTE\Importações.xlsx"
filepath3 = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Box\UTE\RELATÓRIO (version 1).xlsx"
Set Wbtarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SS")
Set wbtarget3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set wbtarget4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data2")
Set wbsource = Workbooks.Open(filepath1)

wbsource.Activate

ReDim Arrayone(1 To Sheets.Count)
ReDim Arraytwo(1 To 2)
For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Arrayone(I) = Sheets(I).Name
    
Next

n = 1
Total = -300
With wbsource.Sheets(n)
    Do Until n = wbsource.Sheets.Count + 1
        Set encontrar = wbsource.Sheets(n).Range("C:AB").Find(What:=KKS, lookAt:=xlPart)
        If encontrar Is Nothing Then
            If Total <> -300 Then
                GoTo Continuar
            End If
        Else
            encontrar.Select
            L = ActiveCell.Row
            C = ActiveCell.Column
            k = 0
            Do Until wbsource.Sheets(n).Range("O" & L) <> wbsource.Sheets(n).Range("O" & L + k)
                k = k + 1
            Loop
        Total = k - 1
        End If
    n = n + 1
    Loop

Continuar:
    n = n - 1
    k = 0
    While k <= Total
        Wbtarget.Range("D" & 8 + k) = wbsource.Sheets(n).Cells(L + k, C).Value
        Wbtarget.Range("E" & 8 + k) = wbsource.Sheets(n).Cells(L + k, C - 10).Value
        Wbtarget.Range("F" & 8 + k) = wbsource.Sheets(n).Cells(L + k, C + 8).Value
        Wbtarget.Range("G" & 8 + k) = wbsource.Sheets(n).Cells(L + k, C - 12).Value
        k = k + 1
    Wend

End With

wbsource.Close


k = 0
If Wbtarget.Range("F" & 8 + k).Value = "" Then
    GoTo Fim
Else
    Set wbsource2 = Workbooks.Open(filepath2)
    wbsource2.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(22).Copy
    wbtarget3.Columns(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wbsource2.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(11).Copy
    wbtarget3.Columns(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wbsource2.Close
    
End If

k = 0
Do Until k = Total
    Set encontrar2 = wbtarget3.Range("A:B").Find(What:=Wbtarget.Range("G" & 8 + k).Value, lookAt:=xlPart)
    If encontrar2 Is Nothing Then
        Wbtarget.Range("I" & 8 + k).Value = "Indisponível"
    Else
        encontrar2.Select
        L2 = ActiveCell.Row
        C2 = ActiveCell.Column
        Wbtarget.Range("H" & 8 + k) = wbtarget3.Cells(L2, 2).Value
        Wbtarget.Range("I" & 8 + k).Value = "Disponível"
    End If
k = k + 1
Loop


Set wbsource3 = Workbooks.Open(filepath3)
wbsource3.Sheets("PEDIDOS C DESCR E PN").Columns(23).Copy
wbtarget4.Columns(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wbsource3.Sheets("PEDIDOS C DESCR E PN").Columns(19).Copy
wbtarget4.Columns(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wbsource3.Close


k = 0
Do Until k = Total
    If Wbtarget.Range("H" & 8 + k).Value <> "" Then
        Set Encontrar3 = wbtarget4.Range("A:B").Find(What:=Wbtarget.Range("H" & 8 + k).Value, lookAt:=xlPart)
        If Encontrar3 Is Nothing Then
            Wbtarget.Range("J" & 8 + k).Value = "Indisponível"
        Else
            Encontrar3.Select
            L3 = ActiveCell.Row
            C3 = ActiveCell.Column
            If wbtarget4.Range("B" & L3).Value <> "" Then
                Wbtarget.Range("J" & 8 + k).Value = "Disponível"
            Else
                Wbtarget.Range("J" & 8 + k).Value = "Indisponível"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Wbtarget.Range("J" & 8 + k).Value = "Indisponível"
    End If
k = k + 1
Loop


Fim:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: For context, what is the actual warning text?

Comment: "this workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe.
if you trust the links , update them to get the latest data. Otherwise, you can keep working with the data you have."

Comment: Try `Set wbsource2 = Workbooks.Open(filepath2, 0)`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you bro